# How to change glossary style for particular instances?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I have a glossary entry for FBI as shown in MWE. At some instance I would like to expand the acronym and emphasize the long version, but with the same glossary entry.

Is it possible to change the style for glossary entries?

As an example, for the second use I need the expanded form of FBI to be emphasized. But in the list of glossaries it should not be emphasized.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc,acronymlists={main}]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\newacronym{fbi}{FBI}{Federal Bureau of Investigation}
\section{First Use}
\gls{fbi}~\lipsum[1]
\glsreset{fbi}\gls{fbi}~\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: What about `\emph{\gls{fbi}}`?